# PHP if condition error syntax error in server

Tags: php, opencart, php-7.2

I have used one if condition and i'm using opencart platform

code is working fine in my local but not in the server

```
<? if ($a == '1') : ?>
   // if something
<? else: ?>
   // else something
<? endif; ?>
```

this code giving me an error in my server

i'm using php version 7.2 in both my local and server

Comment: And which error is that? Is short-tags enabled? You should probably be more explicit and use `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: Use **<?php ?>**

Comment: worth a read: [why we shouldn't use short tags](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code to be like this

```
<?php if ($a == '1') : ?>
// if something
<?php else: ?>
// else something
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

short tags are deprecated. short tags depend on an INI directive and as such are non-portable.

If you enable short tags on server then you will not see error.

It is recommended to use if else statemens without short tags.

for more detail about short tags https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags

Comment: they're not deprecated for all - only 7.4